# Use PHP to reuse common elements in Website(HTML)

Tags: php, html, xampp

Website contains common elements such as header,navigation bar and footer. How should i re-write html pages so that static HTML elements common to my pages are sourced from the same PHP scripts? Can show me some examples?

Example of my html page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="example" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5 PHP" />
  <meta name="author" content="Detonizer"  />
  <title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>
  
    <nav>
        <p class="menu"><a href="page1.html">page1</a></p> 
  <p class="menu"><a href="page2.html">page2</a></p> 
  <p class="menu"><a href="page3.html">page3</a></p> 
  <p class="menu"><a href="page4.html">page4</a></p> 
  <p class="menu"><a href="page5.html">page5</a></p>
        <p class="menu"><a href="page6.html">page6</a></p>   
 </nav>
  
  <footer class="footC" >
  <p class="e1">Example1</p>
  <p class="e2">Example2</p>
  <p class="e3">Example3</p>
  </footer>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Call this **header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="description" content="example" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5 PHP" />
  <meta name="author" content="Detonizer"  />
  <title>Home</title>
</head>
```

Call this **footer.php**

```
<footer class="footC" >
    <p class="e1">Example1</p>
    <p class="e2">Example2</p>
    <p class="e3">Example3</p>
</footer>
```

In your **PHP** pages:

```
<?php include_once 'header.php'; ?>
<body>
    <nav>
        <p class="menu"><a href="page1.html">page1</a></p> 
        <p class="menu"><a href="page2.html">page2</a></p> 
        <p class="menu"><a href="page3.html">page3</a></p> 
        <p class="menu"><a href="page4.html">page4</a></p> 
        <p class="menu"><a href="page5.html">page5</a></p>
        <p class="menu"><a href="page6.html">page6</a></p>   
    </nav>
<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define an index.php file and include different parts different files like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html lang="en">
             <head>
                 <meta charset="utf-8" />
                 <meta name="description" content="example" />
                 <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5 PHP" />
                 <meta name="author" content="Detonizer"  />
                 <title><?php include 'title.php'; ?></title>
             </head>

             <body>

                  <nav>
                       <p class="menu"><a href="page1.html">page1</a></p> 
                       <p class="menu"><a href="page2.html">page2</a></p> 
                       <p class="menu"><a href="page3.html">page3</a></p> 
                       <p class="menu"><a href="page4.html">page4</a></p> 
                       <p class="menu"><a href="page5.html">page5</a></p>
    <p class="menu"><a href="page6.html">page6</a></p>   
                   </nav>
                   <section id="content">
                         <?php include 'content.php'; ?>
                   </section>
                   <footer class="footC" >
                        <p class="e1">Example1</p>
                        <p class="e2">Example2</p>
                        <p class="e3">Example3</p>
                   </footer>

             </body>
          </html>
```